# Basemap plus 3d graph

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

Hello Stackoverflow forks,

I'm a enthusiastic python learner.
I have studied python to visualiza my personal project about population density.

I have gone through tutorials about matplotlib and basemap in python.
I came across with the idea about
mapping my 3dimensional graph on top of the basemap which allows me to use geographycal coordinate information.

Can anyone let me know how I could use basemap as a base plane for the 3dimensional graph?

Please let me know which tutorial or references I could go with for developing this.

Best,
Thank you always Stackoverflow forks.

Answer (score 2):

The [basemap documentation](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html) has a small section on 3D plotting. Here's a simple script to get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
extent = [-127, -65, 25, 51]

# make the map and axis.
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=extent[0], llcrnrlat=extent[2],
             urcrnrlon=extent[1], urcrnrlat=extent[3],
             projection='cyl', resolution='l', fix_aspect=False, ax=ax)
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawstates(linewidth=0.25))
ax.view_init(azim = 230, elev = 15)
ax.set_xlabel(u'Longitude (°E)', labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel(u'Latitude (°N)', labelpad=10)
ax.set_zlabel(u'Altitude (ft)', labelpad=20)

# values to plot - change as needed. Plots 2 dots, one at elevation 0 and another 100.
# also draws a line between the two.
x, y = m(-85.4808, 32.6099)
ax.plot3D([x, x], [y, y], [0, 100], color = 'green', lw = 0.5)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, 100, s = 5, c = 'k', zorder = 4)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, 0, s = 2, c = 'k', zorder = 4)

ax.set_zlim(0., 400.)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Really Really appreciate it. I really had a hard time to find the source that I could take a look, I ran into some other libraries called gdal and something, but it didn't allow me to install that. I spent a ton of time to figure that out but still struggling, I think I can try your stuff first. Appreciate it again.

Comment: Really thankfull to you man! But whay the examples of https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html#adding-3d-bars don,t work correctly?